# Use sscanf to read until a sequence is found

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I would use `strchr` but I want to find a sequence, that looks like this: " %c " - including the spaces.

But I have two issues:

- Is it even possible to match a sequence, and not a set of characters.
- Can you match format specifiers like this "[^%c]" - of course this doesn't work, and I couldn't find any literature that goes deeper into the format.

The goal is to read an undefined number of strings (that, combined, do NOT exceed the buffer size) into a single buffer, until a single space separated character is found:

```
char buf[50];
sscanf("string1 string2 string3 M other input", "%[^ %c ]", buf);
printf("%s", buf); //This would output "string1 string2 string3"
```

Comment: While I usually don't recommend it, this might be a place where *regular expression* would work very well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have a Bash background, so yeah it indeed would. What functions accept regex though?

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you want to do. If it's finding a space-nonspace-space character sequence and stop there, then no, the `scanf` family doesn't work like that.

Comment: If you're on a POSIX platform (Linux, BSD, macOS etc.) then there exists [a set of standard functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html). Unfortunately there's no standard C functions available, and I don't know what's available for Windows.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, It could also be interpreted as "nospace" but the input is restricted to put a char there, so I guess that's why I wrote that. I'll look into the regex.h - if it's even available on windows yet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This'll be a windows binary, but I'll look into it. I guess a fallback would be to just write a while with some ifs...

Comment: @user3121023 `strstr` does not take format specifiers, it just matches strings using binary comparison. I guess that might've not been totally clear unless you read my "until a single space separated character" comment. I mean %c as in any character format specifier.

Comment: @areuz I have a question about the input sequence: could a input string like ```string1 string2 (2 spaces)  string3  (2spaces) ch string4``` be considered?

Comment: @JiaHaoXu No, that is handled elsewhere on the input, so your question is absolutely valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strchr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) can find the first occurance of a character in a string. The end of pattern can be found by comparing the distance between the first non-space ch and the second.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// The input buffer must match the pattern "string string ... ch"
const char* get_endof_pattern(const char *buffer)
{
    const char *first_non_space = buffer;
    const char *second_non_space = strchr(first_non_space, ' ') + 1;
    if (!second_non_space)
        return NULL;

    while (second_non_space - first_non_space > 2) {
        first_non_space = second_non_space;
        second_non_space = strchr(first_non_space, ' ') + 1;

        if (!second_non_space)
            return NULL;
    }

    return first_non_space;
}
```

Comment: There are a few issues with your answer that probably got you those downvotes. You ignored the core issue, being matching space-char-space sequence using sscanf or any other standard function. Also, I stated that "undefined number of strings (that, combined, do NOT exceed the buffer size)" meaning that the input is correct or corrected elsewhere, so there is no need to use dynamic arrays. Also somehow assumed that I'm reading from a file?

Comment: @areuz Thank you for pointing out for me. I didn't understand "[^%c]" when I wrote that answer.

Comment: No problem, I realized too late that not everyone would understand it as the format specifier. Also both yours and @user3121023's answers are indeed correct, but I wrote my own shortened version, with the same principle though. I'll mark you as the correct answer due to your more efficient and readable use of variables.

Comment: @areuz IMHO the return type should be ```const char*``` since its input is ```const char*```. If the users need ```char*```, he/she can do that cast himself/herself.

Comment: True, I just fixed the warning without thinking about it that much. But still `return first_space;` should be `return first_non_space;`.

Comment: @areuz It is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`strspn` and `strcspn` can be used to find a single character surrounded by spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void) {
    char *text[] = { "string1 string2 string3 M other input"
                      , "string1 string2 string3 other input M"
                      , "M string1 string2 string3 other input M"};
    int offset = 0;
    int spaces = 0;
    int length = 0;

    for ( int each = 0; each < 3; each++) {
        offset = 0;
        do {
            spaces = strspn ( text[each] + offset, " ");//consecutive spaces
            offset += spaces;

            length = strcspn ( text[each] + offset, " ");//consecutive not space
            offset += length;

        } while ( 1 != length && 0 != *(text[each] + offset));

        if ( 1 == length) {
            printf ( "[%.*s]\n", offset - ( spaces + length), text[each]);
        }
        else {
            printf ( "[%s]\n", text[each]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```